# Annoying gnome-calendar popups

Tags: gnome, calendar, google-calendar

Since upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 I keep getting gnome-calendar popups asking me for my password to update "holidays in Austria" and "contacts" from Google Calendar. I have removed "holidays in Austria" from my Google Calendar, then reinstalled and removed it again but the popups keep on coming. I no longer need "holidays in Austria". I have both "Feiertage in Deutschland" and "Feiertage in Grossbritannien" in my Google Calendar and they sync with gnome-calendar without this popup appearing.

If anyone knows how to get rid of these annoying popups for a calendar I don't even use, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Found this, but no answer. Tried:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-calendar
```

Logged out/in and annoying calendar was gone, along with popups and unused app-indicator.

This was the only package affected so if ever needed, can always reinstall.

Comment: Did "sudo apt remove gnome-calendar" and rebooted. Popup still keeps on appearing. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @john-rose, been over two years since posting, switched to Mint not long after. gnome-calendar is still installed by default in 20.04 but works w/o the annoying behavior so now I just let it ride. For the classic desktop, I've found Mint the best; way better than Ubuntu w/ gnome-panel. If that's an option you might consider, try it!